# Problem with calculation of y values horizontal line

Tags: pgfplots, calculations

I have a problem with the calculation of the y-values in `pgfplots`.

In my MWE, there seems to be a problem in the calculation of these values.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\small}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis label/.append style={font=\large}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={line width=0.5pt}}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    
    \def\height{16cm}
    \def\width{16cm}
    \def\sc{0.8}
    
    \def\xmin{2}
    \def\xmax{5}
    \def\ymin{0}
    \def\ymax{30000}    
    \def\enlarge{0.05}
    
    \def\Gda{12244}
    \def\Gdb{4773.48}
    \def\Gdc{1861}      % Gdb/Gda*Gdb   
    \def\Gpa{15526.95}
    \def\Gpb{6053.38}   % Gdb/Gda*Gpb
    \def\aa{1.87}
    \def\ab{1.76}
    \def\ac{1.66}       % ab/aa*ab
    \def\reqa{2.67}
    \def\reqb{2.97}
    \def\reqc{3.30} % reqb/reqa*reqb
    \def\va{216.92}
    \def\vb{125.20}
    \def\vc{72.26}      % vb/va*vb
    \def\xva{2.07}
    \def\xvb{0.82}
    \def\xvc{0.33}      % xvb/xva*xvb
    
    \def\f{1}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \definecolor{darkorange}{RGB}{255,140,0}
        \definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,139}        
        
        \begin{axis}[
            height=\height, 
            width=\width, 
            scale only axis=true, 
            scale=\sc, 
            enlarge x limits=\enlarge, 
            enlarge y limits=\enlarge,
            xmin=\xmin,
            xmax=\xmax,
            ymin=\ymin,
            ymax=\ymax,
            restrict x to domain=\xmin:\xmax,
            restrict y to domain=\ymin:\ymax,
            samples=100,
            xlabel=$\mathrm{\p}$, %<- here, I added the result of the calculation for comparison
            ylabel=$\mathrm{V(r)}$,
            ]
            
            \addplot[
            name path global=A,
            color=black,
            smooth,
            ]
            (x,{\Gda*(1-exp(-\aa*(x-\reqa)))^2});
            
            \addplot[
            name path global=B,
            color=black,
            smooth,
            ]
            (x,{\Gpa+\Gdb*(1-exp(-\ab*(x-\reqb)))^2});
            
            \addplot[
            name path global=C,
            color=black,
            smooth,
            ]
            (x,{\Gpa+\Gpb+\Gdc*(1-exp(-\ac*(x-\reqc)))^2});

            \foreach [evaluate=\i as \n using {\va*(\i+0.5)-\xva*(\i+0.5)^2}] \i in {0,1,...,40} {% <- here, I calculate all y-values till 40
                \edef\temp{%
                    \noexpand \path[name path=AA-\i] (axis cs:\xmin,\n) -- (axis cs:\xmax,\n);
                    \noexpand \path[name intersections={of=A and AA-\i},];
                    \noexpand \coordinate (A1-\i)  at (intersection-1);
                    \noexpand \coordinate (B1-\i)  at (intersection-2);
                    \noexpand \draw[line width=0.125pt] (A1-\i) -- (B1-\i);
                }\temp
            }
            
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\o}{\va*(40+0.5)-\xva*(40+0.5)^2} %<- here, as comparison, I calculated the value for 40
            
            \path[name path=AA40] (axis cs:\xmin,\o) -- (axis cs:\xmax,\o);
            \path[name intersections={of=A and AA40}];
            \coordinate (A40)  at (intersection-1);
            \coordinate (B40)  at (intersection-2);
            \draw[darkorange, line width=0.125pt] (A40) -- (B40);
            
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\p}{\Gpa+\vb*(20+0.5)-\xvb*(20+0.5)^2} %<- the correct value should be 17748.95, but the system gives me 16039.39
            
            \path[name path=BB20] (axis cs:\xmin,\p) -- (axis cs:\xmax,\p);
            \path[name intersections={of=B and BB20}];
            \coordinate (A20)  at (intersection-1);
            \coordinate (B20)  at (intersection-2);
            \draw[darkorange, line width=0.125pt] (A20) -- (B20);   
        \end{axis}  
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem should come from the `\Gpa+` argument, since the calculation without this argument is correct.

The error I get running the MWE is `Dimension too large. ...ro{\p}{\Gpa+\vb*(20+0.5)-\xvb*(20+0.5)^2}`

Comment: divide all y-values by 10^4 or 10^3 and set the y label accordingly

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda Sorry, but you were right. I added the factor in front of each argument like `\f*\Gpa + \f*...` and now it works fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda, do you want to write an answer or shall we close this question as "answered in the comments"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All calculations performed by the pgf math engine must not exceed ±16383.99999 at any point.
Thus the workaround could be to divide all y-values by 10^4 or 10^3 and set accordingly the y label of the plot.